# Python dataframe grouping

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to provide average movie’s ratings by the following four time intervals during which the movies were released (a) 1970 to 1979 (b) 1980 to 1989, ect.. and I wonder what did I wrong here, since I'm new to DS.

EDIT

1. Since the dataset have no year column, I extract the released year embedded in the title column and assign a new column to the dataset:

```
year = df['title'].str.findall('\((\d{4})\)').str.get(0)
year_df = df.assign(year = year.values)
```

1.5. Because there are some str in the column, I convert the entire "year" column to int. Then I implemented groupby function to group the year in 10 years interval.

```
year_df['year'] = year_df['year'].astype(int)
year_df = year_df.groupby(year_df.year // 10 * 10)
```

2. After that, I want to assign the year group into an interval of 10 years:

```
year_desc = { 1910: "1910 – 1019", 1920: "1920 – 1929", 1930: "1930 – 1939", 1940: "1940 – 1949", 1950: "1950 – 1959",1960: "1960 – 1969",1970: "1970 – 1979",1980: "1980 – 1989",1990: "1990 – 1999",2000: "2000 – 2009"}
year_df['year'] = [year_desc[x] for x in year_df['year']]
```

When I run my code after trying to assign year group, I get an error stated that:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

UPDATES:

I tried to follow @ozacha suggestion and I still experiencing error, but this time is

> 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'map'

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1) Your `year_df` already has a `year` column, so there is no need to recreate it using `df.assign()`. `.assign()` is an alternative way of (re)defining columns in a dataframe.

Ad 2) Not sure what your `test_group` is, so it is difficult to get what's the source of the error. However, I believe this is what you want – using [pd.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
year_df = ...
year_df['year'] = year_df['year'].astype(int)
year_desc = {...}
year_df['year_group'] = year_df['year'].map(year_desc)
```

Alternatively, you can also generate year groups dynamically:

```
year_df['year_group'] = year_df['year'].map(lambda year: f"{year} – {year + 9}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! So, the test_group is a just a copied dataframe form the original. I tried both of your suggestions and this time around I got an error saying: "'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'map'" Any thought on what would it might be?

Comment: `groupby` is used for grouping rows into logical sets that allow you to apply aggregations or transformations.
Replace your part 1.5 with `year_df['year'] = year_df['year'].astype(int).round(-1)` instead

Comment: Everything works now! Thank you so much!